# In Angular 6, How to check whether formControl value has changed in each focusout?

Tags: angular, forms, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

I have an **@Input** variable in a child component - measure is in Inches.
My form has 2 input text controls - 1. **Foot** 2. **Inches**
I convert the @Input to foot & inches.
Only if the values changed in the form, on **focusOut**, it should **emit** the value to the parent.

**the real issue is, my focusout emits every time without checking value has changed or not.**

the scenario is,

1. I have an initial value as @Input
2. On change i am doing some calculations and propagates it.
3. once I entered value focus out - till this point the code works well.
4. again give focus-in then focus-out without changing it.
5. the second time I have to check whether I edited the previous value. Because with the emit, something goes wrong and the value changes happening.

Comment: In your child component, with the @input, can you test if the values are the same, and if they are, exit without the emit?

Comment: @DanielG, updated the Q. Could you please check?

Comment: https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#updateOn

Answer (score 0):

We could make use of `NgOnChanges` to compare `@Input` prop previous value and current value. If current value is something else than previous value, we do something.

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnChanges {

  @Input() textValue;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    const text: SimpleChange = changes.textValue;

    if (text.currentValue !== undefined && text.previousValue !== undefined) {
      console.log('prev value: ', text.previousValue);
      console.log('current value: ', text.currentValue);
      if (text.previousValue !== text.currentValue) {
        console.log('new different value!');
        // do something here with text.currentValue
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Or listen for `focusout` event with `Hostlistener` to capture value emitted with the event. Compare event value form input to previous value in child component value.

```js
@HostListener('focusout', ["$event.target.value"])

  onFocusOut(inputValue) {

    console.log('input value on focus out', inputValue);

    if (this.textValue !== inputValue) {
    console.log('new different value!');
        // do something here with inputValue
    }

  }
```

I would preferer `ngOnChanges` approach. It makes a cleaner read, avoids some extra listener, we get to use `SimpleChanges` obj for other Inputs. However, with `OnChanges` change detection is run on prop change only. If for some reason you always do want to run these checks with `focusOut` (regardless of input change) then `Hostlistener` would be the way to go with my examples.